# Printing listbox Items in order of occurence

Tags: c#, printing

I have an application that I have built and is just sort of printing app.
First I populate ListBox and format it then goto c:\somefolder
in some folder are pdf files it looks on listbox and see if there is any file name that matches an item on the listbox and sends it to the default printer.Everything is working great ,but say I have JohnDoe.pdf,ShahRukh.pdf,Vijay.pdf
how can I make it to send the files in that order, for now it works great ,but I want to be able to print ==> JohnDoe.pdf first, then ShahRukh.pdf and so on and so forth.Please if you have any idea to spare is much welcome.
Thanks in advance. This what I have right now it works great but print all items that match but randomly .I want it to respond or print matches in order of occurrence from top to bottom.

```
public class Pdf
{
    public static Boolean PrintPDFs(string pdfFileName)
    {
        try
        {
            ProcessStartInfo stackOverflowHelp = new ProcessStartInfo();
            stackOverflowHelp.Verb = "print";
            stackOverflowHelp.FileName = pdfFileName;
            stackOverflowHelp.CreateNoWindow = true;
            stackOverflowHelp.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;

            Process gamingBoy = new Process();
            gamingBoy.StartInfo = stackOverflowHelp;
            gamingBoy.Start();
            gamingBoy.WaitForInputIdle();

            if (gamingBoy.HasExited == false)
            {
                gamingBoy.WaitForExit(20000);
                //return true;
            }
            //  System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
            gamingBoy.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
            gamingBoy.Close();
            //  return true;
            //proc.Close();
            //KillAdobe("AcroRd32");
            return true;
        }
        catch
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string dir = @"C:\slim\slimyyyy";//
    if (Directory.Exists(dir))//If a directory defined above exists then do the followings
    {
        string[] pdf_Files = Directory.GetFiles(dir);
        if (pdf_Files.Length > 0)
        {
            foreach (string file in pdf_Files) 
            {
                string fileName = Path.GetFileName(file);
                foreach (object item in listBox1.Items)
                {
                    if (fileName == line.ToString())
                    {
                        Pdf.PrintPDFs((file));
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just reverse the order of your `foreach` loops:

```
foreach (object item in listBox1.Items)
{
     foreach (string file in pdf_Files) 
     {
         string fileName = Path.GetFileName(f);
         if (fileName == line.ToString())
         {
              Pdf.PrintPDFs((file));
         }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hey Stan your code works the first two times you run the App,but after the third time it prints randomly again, and more so it starts to print from bottom to top,at least there is an order if I only I could just make it permanent, don't care if it starts top to bottom or bottom to top as long as is one of them and is permanent

Answer (score 0):

The easy answer is to change the order of your loops. That is, change your loop to:

```
foreach (var item in listBox1.Items)
{
    var fname = item.ToString();
    if (pdf_files.Contains(fname))
    {
        Pdf.PrintPDFs(fname);
    }
}
```

Comment: H,i thanks Jim not happened when implemented your code.

Comment: The code I showed should print the files in the order that they appear in the list box. If that's not the behavior you want, then you need to edit your question and explain more clearly what your listbox contains (in order), what your list of files contains (in order), what you expect the output to be, and what the output actually is. If you're getting an error then tell us *exactly* what the error message says, and on what line it occurs.

Comment: Thats exactly what I want Jim, but may be am doing something wrong with implementing it.